# Performance degradation on cassandra cluster from 1 node to 4 node

Tags: performance, cassandra, cluster-computing

I am running the cassandra stress test on **vm's**. Below are the throughput results of cassandra cluster with defalut configuration.

**Throughput**

> 1 node : 22000 - 26000
>
> 2 node : 17000 - 20000
>
> 3 node : 16000 - 19000
>
> 4 node : 12000 - 16000

There are no any bottlenecks on CPU, network, disk, memory, JVM_Heap.

**Cassandra.yaml**

> cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
>
> num_tokens: 256
>
> seeds: "vm1"
>
> listen_address: vm2
>
> rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
>
> endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch

Could you please tell me the reason for degradation of the performance while adding the nodes?

Adding some more information

I reinstalled the cassandra on two vm's. Surprising results are not that bad but there are **no  improvements** in the 2 node cluster compared to single node.

### Output of the 2 node cluster

**Stress on localhost**

root@gsedb3:~/dsc-cassandra-2.0.9/tools/bin# ./cassandra-stress

> Unable to create stress keyspace: Keyspace names must be case-insensitively unique ("Keyspace1" conflicts with "Keyspace1")
>
> Averages from the middle 80% of values:
>
> interval_op_rate          : 20363
>
> interval_key_rate         : 20363
>
> latency median            : 1.5
>
> latency 95th percentile   : 5.1
>
> latency 99.9th percentile : 109.1
>
> Total operation time      : 00:00:49
>
> END

**Stress on gsedb3,gsedb4**

root@gsedb3:~/dsc-cassandra-2.0.9/tools/bin# ./cassandra-stress -d gsedb3,gsedb4

> Unable to create stress keyspace: Keyspace names must be case-insensitively unique ("Keyspace1" conflicts with "Keyspace1")
>
> Averages from the middle 80% of values:
>
> interval_op_rate          : 16420
>
> interval_key_rate         : 16420
>
> latency median            : 1.7
>
> latency 95th percentile   : 6.9
>
> latency 99.9th percentile : 68.4
>
> Total operation time      : 00:01:03

**Stress with 400 threads**

root@gsedb3:~/dsc-cassandra-2.0.9/tools/bin# ./cassandra-stress -t 400

> Averages from the middle 80% of values:
>
> interval_op_rate          : 24841
>
> interval_key_rate         : 24841
>
> latency median            : 4.0
>
> latency 95th percentile   : 32.2
>
> latency 99.9th percentile : 196.5
>
> Total operation time      : 00:00:41

**Stress with 400 threads on gsedb3,gsedb4**

root@gsedb3:~/dsc-cassandra-2.0.9/tools/bin# ./cassandra-stress -d gsedb3,gsedb4 -t 400

> Unable to create stress keyspace: Keyspace names must be case-insensitively unique >>("Keyspace1" conflicts with "Keyspace1")
>
> Averages from the middle 80% of values:
>
> interval_op_rate          : 25273
>
> interval_key_rate         : 25273
>
> latency median            : 3.9
>
> latency 95th percentile   : 26.9
>
> latency 99.9th percentile : 252.8
>
> Total operation time      : 00:00:40

Comment: How did you get these results? Did you use cassandra-stress tool from separate machine?

Comment: @Shutty: Im running cassandra-stress tool on **vm1**. Below are the Cassandra.yaml settings                                          cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'                               num_tokens: 256                                                seeds: "vm1"                                           listen_address: vm2                                      rpc_address: 0.0.0.0                                  endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch

Answer (score 3):

You are running out of cassandra-stress not Cassandra. Typically you'll need to have more stress machines compared to the number of servers under test (2-4/1 ratio). One thing you can try to increase the amount of throughput is increasing the thread count on the stress instance.

Your goal should be to find the final capacity of the server based on CPU or IO limits. (IO will be the first to go)